# Determine device ID of a camera with a specified facing mode

Tags: javascript, navigator, mediadevices

I am working on code to allow for an in-page `select` element to choose a camera.  The default camera should be the "environment" camera while the rest should be listed after.

Using the following call I am able to stream video from an appropriate "environment"-facing camera:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: "environment"} }).then(function (stream) {
    // display stream on web page
    ...
});
```

Similarly, I can get the list of available devices using the following:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(
    devices => {
        // build list of options
    }
);
```

I store the `deviceId` for each option and use that to display the feed from that camera which works well.

However, the option selected by default is not necessarily the "environment" camera.  And the stream object returned from `getUserMedia` doesn't seem to have an easy way to determine the `deviceId` of the device providing that stream.  Nor can I seem to find any other way to determine the "environment"-facing camera.

Is this not possible or is there some kind of `getDeviceIdForFacingMode` function that I've just missed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After digging through the objects a bit more I was ultimately able to find that the following works to get the `deviceId` from the stream:

```
stream.getVideoTracks()[0].getSettings().deviceId
```

I would assume that in other cases you may need to get careful about the `[0]` if for some reason your stream involved multiple video tracks but for my purposes this worked well.  In general I would expect you could get whatever information you need between `stream.getVideoTracks()[i]` ([MediaStreamTrack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack)) and `stream.getVideoTracks()[i].getSettings()` ([MediaTrackSettings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackSettings)).